# What can I remove from system directory to increase space?

Tags: 16.04

I'm a Windows man, I don't know which subdirectories I can clean from system directory
[image]

Comment: probably your safest options are to remove any programs you won't be using, then `sudo apt-get autoclean; sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the output of `df -h` ?

Comment: If you're a windows man I don't get why you want to increase space in the first place. 13GB is not quite much. Windows needs way more space without anything installed. I would increase the space instead of deleting anything. If you can't increase space you should think about using a more minimal linux distribution.

Comment: You can remove old linux kernels, and keep only the two newest versions. But it will usually not make a big difference. It will make a bigger difference to remove programs you won't be using. (It is easy to re-install a program, if you would need it in the future). But often the main amount of data are personal data, files that you have downloaded and collected. Housecleaning among those files, wherever you keep them, can usually make a huge difference.

Comment: I can't load your image ("secure connection failed") but generally speaking, you shouldn't remove anything from a system directory directly, especially if you're a Windows man.